# Get y-offset value of all views inside Flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am rendering atleast 5 `View` inside a `Flatlist`. I am trying to store the y-offset value of each view inside a state array. But the value that the state receives is 0. How do I make sure that I get the correct y-offset value saved to my state array?

Here is my code

```
<Flatlist 
   data={data}
   renderItem = {({ item }) => {
       return (
          <View
              onLayout={event => this.setState({ yArray : [...this.state.yArray, event.nativeEvent.layout.y] })}
          >
              <Text>Something</Text>
          </View>
       )
   }}
/>
```

When I do `console.log(this.state.yArray)`, it output `[0]`

I expected it to be something like `[30, 80, 130, ...]`

So, there are two issues:
1. The y offset is always 0
2. y offset values aren't pushed into the array.